# AWS S3 - Access Denied; Block all is off, ACL is everyone, Policy is allow all

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket where Block all public access is unchecked, ACL is set to allow Everyone for all List/Write/Read, and there's a valid generated policy from S3 that has s3:* for the valid resource name with a wildcard per documentation...  Cache has been double checked, can't figure out what's going on with AWS S3.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=316341

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to access S3 from another AWS resource?

Comment: @jpetty no just public web access

Comment: Did you check your account level public access block setting? BTW hope you know this is really bad practice. Even if you are hosting S3 website this is still way too open.

Comment: @congbaoguier I added screenshots above, "Everyone" has full access. And yes I'm familiar with the practice, this is for a case study / experiment, but it should work.

Comment: Have you verified that the object you are requesting exists? No typos in the name? You will get an access denied error if you request an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you enable hosting? and add rewrite rule?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth yes, I'm not getting an error message i'm getting an "Access Denied".

Comment: @TuanVA yep tried that too, no luck on the objects.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are wanting to create a bucket that is "Public", meaning that anyone can access content from the bucket as long as they know the name of the object.

To make this happen:

- Turn off "Block Public Access"
- Create a Bucket Policy like the one you have shown above

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

That will be sufficient for all content to be accessible.

To test that it is working, you can use the Amazon S3 management console. Select an object in the bucket, then use the **Object URL** to access the object. This will avoid any typing errors and will attempt to access the object anonymously (as opposed to the **Open** button that adds a signature for private access).

If it is not working for your bucket, I suggest that you perform an experiment by creating a new bucket and following the above steps to make it public. If it works, you can then compare the differences between the two buckets.

It is possible that Block Public Access has been applied at the account-level.

Comment: Per my subject line, context, and screenshots: "Block all is off, ACL is everyone, Policy is allow all".  Those were all attempted already, I may have found a bug with S3...

Comment: As a test, did you try creating a new bucket and applying the above steps to it? This would assist identifying whether it could be related to your AWS Account.

Comment: The issue is pertaining to SES/receiving-email, the email routing to S3 object rather a SNS topic.  It seems that the object written is being assigned to "Everyone" but missing the read/write permission.  Hopefully that helps point some direction here.

Comment: Is the object being created from a different AWS account? If you manually upload an object, is it publicly accessible?

Comment: If I upload the file, yes I am able to access via public. The objects I'm having issues with are those created by SES, but still the same AWS account.

Comment: Are they possibly being encrypted by KMS when stored in the bucket? That would prohibit "anonymous" access to the files.

Comment: I do not have Encryption enabled (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html), per the documentation they should not be getting any encryption (which they're not when I manually make the file public and view).

Comment: can you reach out to your team for this matter?